# (Unity 5) Weird Touch Behavior

Tags: android, unity, touch

In my (Google Cardboard) Android app I would like to make my camera move on Touch. That movement state should be controlled via a "switch", so when I touch the screen the camera starts to move and when I tap again it stops. To achieve that I appended this script to the camera:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TapControl : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public int state = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        state += 1;
    }
    if (state % 2 == 0)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The state-integer increases every touch. But nonethless, the camera's behavior can be described as a "hold-touch to move" when the state-variable is even.

So, to make it short: Can anyone detect any programming mistakes i made that could cause this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your state integer into a state boolean, as below.

[Edit] I added the block to make sure the touch count is greater than zero.  All sample code I read does this.

Also, your speed in your code is zero. Just making sure you initialized it to a value.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TapControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public bool isCameraMoving = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                isCameraMoving = !isCameraMoving; // Toggle moving state
            }
        }

        if (isCameraMoving)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Before my seemingly unnecessairily complicated program snipped I posted, I actually had the boolean-solution, but that gave me the same errors. The speed I just defined in the Unity inspector. I will give your idea a try and inform you about the result, but I think that it is a conflict with the scripts that are included and applied to the Google Cardboard-Camera(s) by default.